# PostgreSQL: update json issue

Tags: json, postgresql

Table has a json-column named "stats" with the following value: {"countValue":0}

I'm trying to update this value by:

```
 UPDATE my_table
 SET stats = jsonb_set(stats, '{countValue}', 1);
```

But receive the following error:

```
 No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried to fix the problem, by applying explicit type cast for countValue (countValue::text), but with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use jsonb type on `'1'` instead of integer from `jsonb_set` function signature

> jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])

```
UPDATE my_table
SET stats = jsonb_set(stats, '{countValue}', '1');
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=404812dc5a6b8a7c313c33415afa0f66)